# A contradiction involving the compact set definition

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, compactness

The definition states that for all open coverage of $ X $, there is a finite open undercoverage that also covers X
Question: The union of open finites is open, so how can I unite open finites and have a closed one? Would not that be a contradiction?

Comment: why do you need to take a subcover (undercoverage) to get a contradiction? The union of any arbitrary, finite or infinite, number of open sets is open. Wouldn't this result in the same "contradiction" (using the original cover, or coverage)?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that is required is that the union of that finite set of open sets **contains** $X$, not that it is **equal** no $X$.

Besides (but hardly relevant here), you seem to believe that a set cannot be both open and closed. Yes, it can.

Answer (score 1):

The space $X$ itself is both open and closed,  as its complement,  $\emptyset$, is open and closed.